# How to convert this ActiveRecord::Observer to a Service object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, observers, sidekiq

How would one convert the following ActiveRecord::Observer to a Service object (or maybe multiple objects)?

The `PushService` updates all connected browsers via WebSocket of all changes. It does this by POST-ing to an external process. Since migrating from `Thread.new` to Sidekiq, the observer broke. A Sidekiq job started in an :after_create can run before the transaction is actually committed, so it will raise an ActiveRecord::NotFound error.

It is recommended to use an :after_commit hook, but then information needed by the `PushService` such as `record.changes` will not be available.

The interesting use case that this observer fulfills is that when a new message is created, which is a reply to another message. It will automatically run two callbacks. An :after_create for the reply-message and an :after_touch for the thread-message.

I am interested to see how this behavior can be run by using an explicit service object.

```
class PushObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
    observe :message

  def after_create(record)
    Rails.logger.info "[Observe] create #{record.inspect}"
    PushService.new(:create, record).publish
  end

  def after_update(record)
    Rails.logger.info "[Observe] update #{record.changed.inspect}"
    PushService.new(:update, record).publish
  end

  def after_touch(record)
    Rails.logger.info "[Observe] touched #{record.changes.inspect}"
    PushService.new(:touch, record).publish
  end

  def after_destroy(record)
    Rails.logger.info "[Observe] destroy #{record.inspect}"
    PushService.new(:destroy, record).publish
  end
end
```

Comment: Hello! Did you find solution for your problem? We've stuck with the same problem and can't figure out what to do

Answer (score 1):

You can set up subscribers and listeners using a gem called [wisper](https://github.com/krisleech/wisper).

So in your PushService class, you would include `Wisper::Publisher` There is an exact example on the Github page for using this as a service. This way, the firing off of events will be taken care of the actual objects.

So whenever PushService does something that requires updating connected browsers

```
def some_action
  #some code
  publish(:done_something, self)
end
```

Then the Service object can be listening for this event with the `subscribe` method.